# Coredata not giving data on fetch request

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

in my app while i start my app and i fetch data from coredata. its not giving me data.

but if i not closed my app and save some data in database and without close my app if i fetch data its giving me a data.

and when i close my app. next time again its not giving me data.

Here is my code

```
self.FetchAllLocalData({ (Available) in
                if (Available == "0")
                {
                    for ValueToSave in detailArray!
                    {
                        let entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("RxOrder", inManagedObjectContext: moc)
                        print(ValueToSave.id!)

                        var medicinetype : String = ""
                        let Id : String = ValueToSave.id!.description
                        let isRx : String = ValueToSave.isRxMedicine!.description
                        print(ValueToSave.medicineTypeId)
                        if (ValueToSave.medicineTypeId != nil)
                        {
                            medicinetype = ValueToSave.medicineTypeId!
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            medicinetype = "0"
                        }

                        let medicineName : String = ValueToSave.name!
                        let orderId : String = ValueToSave.orderId!.description
                        let price : String = "0"
                        let quantity : String = ValueToSave.quentity!.description
                        let strength : String = ValueToSave.strength!


                        entity.setValue(Id, forKey: "medicineId")
                        entity.setValue(isRx, forKey: "isRxMedicine")
                        entity.setValue(medicinetype, forKey: "medicineType")
                        entity.setValue(medicineName, forKey: "productName")
                        entity.setValue(self.order_id_RX_Medicine!, forKey: "OrderId")
                        entity.setValue(price, forKey: "price")
                        entity.setValue(quantity, forKey: "quantity")
                        entity.setValue(strength, forKey: "strength")


                        do{
                            try moc.save()
                        }
                        catch {
                            fatalError("failed To Save Content\(error)")
                        }


                    }
```

and this one for fetching

```
func  FetchAllLocalData(completion : (Available : String)-> Void)  {
     let request : NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "RxOrder")


    do{


        //request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "orderId == \(order_id_RX_Medicine!)")
        let fetchedPerson = try moc.executeFetchRequest(request)
        DataAvailable = fetchedPerson as! [NSManagedObject]
        print(DataAvailable.count)

        if (DataAvailable.count > 0)
        {
            print(DataAvailable[0].valueForKey("orderId"))
            for OldData in DataAvailable {
                print(DataAvailable.count)

                print(order_id_RX_Medicine)
                print(OldData.valueForKey("orderId"))
                if (OldData.valueForKey("orderId")! as! String == order_id_RX_Medicine)
                {
                   completion(Available: "1")
                }
                else
                {
                    completion(Available: "0")
                }

            }

        }
        else
        {
           completion(Available: "0")
        }

    }

    catch
    {
        completion(Available: "0")
        fatalError("Something Went Wrong \(error)")
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, since you are here and there are `print` statements in your code I am going to assume you are seeing those fire and you are not getting an error when your application runs.

Therefore, it would be helpful to see your Core Data creation code.

It would also be helpful to see how you get the `moc` into the creation code.  Is the creation code in the AppDelegate or somewhere else?

What type of persistent store are you using?

Answer (score -1):

You must try this in your app delegate :

```
    func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    AppDelegate.shared.saveContext()
}
```

This will save your data before app terminates